# NextJs deployment on kubernetes showing 404 on static resource

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js, vercel

I have a web application written on NextJs. To deploy it on kubernetes, first I wrote following Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12-alpine as node

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

ADD ./package.json ./

COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache git curl
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

And following is my kubernetes deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: www-server
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: www-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: www-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: www-server:cc57243
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: server
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 15
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: www-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: server
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: server
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 15
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 500Mi
        startupProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: server
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 15
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: aws-ecr-login
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

During the deployment, while I am browsing the server it's showing following error on js files
`_next/static/DdLeVH51NHNpJfvX3wxJT/_buildManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

[image: Screenshot while browsing]

What I am missing to make the deployment with 0 downtime configuration?

Comment: This Github [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12578) might be useful for your issue.

Comment: You could use docker-compose, do you still have this problem?